# Set height of div using JS to match the bottom position of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set the height of **Div X** to match bottom of **Div N**. Constraint: These containers are not nested and they can't be nested so a HTML/CSS solution will not be applicable. **Div X** height must be set using JS.

An approach which works is to sum the height of all **Div 1 thru Div N** items and then set the height of **Div X**.

--

**Question:**

I'm searching for an alternative solution. Maybe a browser API like `getBoundingClientRect` could work but I'm unsure of how to implement.

Or any other browser API's?

[image: graphic explainer]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I didn't write it yet because I'm trying to consider some possible implementations but @Cache posted an answer which works if that helps with suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
let height = 0
let node = document.querySelector('DIV_N')
while(true) {​​​​
    height += node.getBoundingClientRect().height
    if (node.classList.contains('DIV_1')) break
    node = node.previousSibling
}​​​​
document.querySelector('.DIV_X').style.height = height + 'px'
```